# asp.net webapi selfhost controllers from another project

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, owin, self-host-webapi

I have a `webapi2` project and I want to selfhost this api in another project and call the methods with a `httpClient`. Here is my code:

```
namespace TestSelfHosting.Controllers
{
    public class ProductsController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public string GetProduct()
        {
            return "test";
        }
    }
}
```

And the code from the test project:

```
namespace TestSelfHosting.Tests
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
        {
            // Configure Web API for self-host. 
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
        }
    }
}

namespace TestSelfHosting.Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            const string baseAddress = "http://localhost:9000/";

            // Start OWIN host 
            using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress))
            {
                // Create HttpCient and make a request to api/values 
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

                var response = client.GetAsync(baseAddress + "api/products").Result;

                var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I'm calling `client.GetAsync` method, is throwing an error (404, not found). Is this possible to achieve or am I doing something wrong?

I've followed the tutorial from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api)

Comment: Have you tried to call the method Get instead of GetProduct?

Comment: as you can see, if I am using get verb with no action, it is suposed to call the method GetProducts. If I call from postman this url, it's returning the string test

Answer (score -1):

Have you referenced your webapi2 project in the self-host project (test project)?

If not, go to your self-host project -> references -> add reference -> locate your webapi2.dll and add it (you must build your webapi2 project beforehand to “generate” the dll file)